# WSO2is as service provider for Mattermost CE

Tags: git, oauth-2.0, keycloak, mattermost, wso2-identity-server

I'm trying to use WSO2is as a service provider for Mattermost CE. My idea is to use the Mattermost GitHub social login feature with WSO2is instead of GitHub.

To do that, I have configured Wso2is with Oauth service provider, which works fine. I'm able to authenticate myself and Mattermost accept the token. However, Mattermost can't log me in.

After some digging, I strongly suggest that this issue came from Claims. Mattermost and Wso2is can't speak the same "language". I have tried lots of unsuccessful configurations, especially with http://wso2.org/oidc/claim.

I'm wondering if anyone knows how to configure Wso2is with Mattermost?

For information, this is one of my tested configurations :

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><ServiceProvider>
  <ApplicationName>Mattermost</ApplicationName>
  <Description>test</Description>
  <InboundAuthenticationConfig>
    <InboundAuthenticationRequestConfigs>
      <InboundAuthenticationRequestConfig>
        <InboundAuthKey>Mattermost</InboundAuthKey>
        <InboundAuthType>openid</InboundAuthType>
        <InboundConfigType>standardAPP</InboundConfigType>
        <Properties/>
      </InboundAuthenticationRequestConfig>
      <InboundAuthenticationRequestConfig>
        <InboundAuthKey>Mattermost</InboundAuthKey>
        <InboundAuthType>passivests</InboundAuthType>
        <InboundConfigType>standardAPP</InboundConfigType>
        <Properties/>
      </InboundAuthenticationRequestConfig>
      <InboundAuthenticationRequestConfig>
        <InboundAuthKey>_FPI1OvbJHV_3In6kdYiQMmnIZIa</InboundAuthKey>
        <InboundAuthType>oauth2</InboundAuthType>
        <InboundConfigType>standardAPP</InboundConfigType>
        <inboundConfiguration><![CDATA[<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<oAuthAppDO>
    <oauthConsumerKey>_FPI1OvbJHV_3In6kdYiQMmnIZIa</oauthConsumerKey>
    <oauthConsumerSecret>tPelnXdrnQjr0cpn2pxPT9YuQkUa</oauthConsumerSecret>
    <applicationName>Mattermost</applicationName>
    <callbackUrl>https://team.ticoop.fr/signup/gitlab/complete</callbackUrl>
    <oauthVersion>OAuth-2.0</oauthVersion>
    <grantTypes>refresh_token urn:ietf:params:oauth:grant-type:saml2-bearer implicit password client_credentials iwa:ntlm authorization_code urn:ietf:params:oauth:grant-type:jwt-bearer </grantTypes>
    <scopeValidators/>
    <pkceSupportPlain>true</pkceSupportPlain>
    <pkceMandatory>false</pkceMandatory>
    <userAccessTokenExpiryTime>3600</userAccessTokenExpiryTime>
    <applicationAccessTokenExpiryTime>3600</applicationAccessTokenExpiryTime>
    <refreshTokenExpiryTime>84600</refreshTokenExpiryTime>
    <idTokenExpiryTime>3600</idTokenExpiryTime>
    <audiences/>
    <bypassClientCredentials>false</bypassClientCredentials>
    <requestObjectSignatureValidationEnabled>false</requestObjectSignatureValidationEnabled>
    <idTokenEncryptionEnabled>false</idTokenEncryptionEnabled>
    <idTokenEncryptionAlgorithm>null</idTokenEncryptionAlgorithm>
    <idTokenEncryptionMethod>null</idTokenEncryptionMethod>
    <backChannelLogoutUrl></backChannelLogoutUrl>
    <tokenType>JWT</tokenType>
</oAuthAppDO>
]]></inboundConfiguration>
        <Properties/>
      </InboundAuthenticationRequestConfig>
    </InboundAuthenticationRequestConfigs>
  </InboundAuthenticationConfig>
  <LocalAndOutBoundAuthenticationConfig>
    <AuthenticationSteps/>
    <AuthenticationType>default</AuthenticationType>
    <alwaysSendBackAuthenticatedListOfIdPs>false</alwaysSendBackAuthenticatedListOfIdPs>
    <subjectClaimUri>http://wso2.org/claims/emailaddress</subjectClaimUri>
    <UseTenantDomainInUsername>false</UseTenantDomainInUsername>
    <UseUserstoreDomainInRoles>true</UseUserstoreDomainInRoles>
    <UseUserstoreDomainInUsername>false</UseUserstoreDomainInUsername>
    <EnableAuthorization>false</EnableAuthorization>
  </LocalAndOutBoundAuthenticationConfig>
  <RequestPathAuthenticatorConfigs/>
  <InboundProvisioningConfig>
    <ProvisioningUserStore/>
    <IsProvisioningEnabled>false</IsProvisioningEnabled>
    <IsDumbModeEnabled>false</IsDumbModeEnabled>
  </InboundProvisioningConfig>
  <OutboundProvisioningConfig>
    <ProvisioningIdentityProviders/>
  </OutboundProvisioningConfig>
  <ClaimConfig>
    <RoleClaimURI/>
    <LocalClaimDialect>true</LocalClaimDialect>
    <IdpClaim/>
    <ClaimMappings>
      <ClaimMapping>
        <LocalClaim>
          <ClaimUri>http://wso2.org/claims/username</ClaimUri>
          <claimId>0</claimId>
        </LocalClaim>
        <RemoteClaim>
          <ClaimUri>http://wso2.org/claims/username</ClaimUri>
          <claimId>0</claimId>
        </RemoteClaim>
        <RequestClaim>true</RequestClaim>
        <MandatoryClaim>false</MandatoryClaim>
      </ClaimMapping>
      <ClaimMapping>
        <LocalClaim>
          <ClaimUri>http://wso2.org/claims/fullname</ClaimUri>
          <claimId>0</claimId>
        </LocalClaim>
        <RemoteClaim>
          <ClaimUri>http://wso2.org/claims/fullname</ClaimUri>
          <claimId>0</claimId>
        </RemoteClaim>
        <RequestClaim>true</RequestClaim>
        <MandatoryClaim>false</MandatoryClaim>
      </ClaimMapping>
      <ClaimMapping>
        <LocalClaim>
          <ClaimUri>http://wso2.org/claims/photourl</ClaimUri>
          <claimId>0</claimId>
        </LocalClaim>
        <RemoteClaim>
          <ClaimUri>http://wso2.org/claims/photourl</ClaimUri>
          <claimId>0</claimId>
        </RemoteClaim>
        <RequestClaim>true</RequestClaim>
        <MandatoryClaim>false</MandatoryClaim>
      </ClaimMapping>
      <ClaimMapping>
        <LocalClaim>
          <ClaimUri>http://wso2.org/claims/emailaddress</ClaimUri>
          <claimId>0</claimId>
        </LocalClaim>
        <RemoteClaim>
          <ClaimUri>http://wso2.org/claims/emailaddress</ClaimUri>
          <claimId>0</claimId>
        </RemoteClaim>
        <RequestClaim>true</RequestClaim>
        <MandatoryClaim>false</MandatoryClaim>
      </ClaimMapping>
      <ClaimMapping>
        <LocalClaim>
          <ClaimUri>http://wso2.org/claims/url</ClaimUri>
          <claimId>0</claimId>
        </LocalClaim>
        <RemoteClaim>
          <ClaimUri>http://wso2.org/claims/url</ClaimUri>
          <claimId>0</claimId>
        </RemoteClaim>
        <RequestClaim>true</RequestClaim>
        <MandatoryClaim>false</MandatoryClaim>
      </ClaimMapping>
      <ClaimMapping>
        <LocalClaim>
          <ClaimUri>http://wso2.org/claims/active</ClaimUri>
          <claimId>0</claimId>
        </LocalClaim>
        <RemoteClaim>
          <ClaimUri>http://wso2.org/claims/active</ClaimUri>
          <claimId>0</claimId>
        </RemoteClaim>
        <RequestClaim>true</RequestClaim>
        <MandatoryClaim>false</MandatoryClaim>
      </ClaimMapping>
      <ClaimMapping>
        <LocalClaim>
          <ClaimUri>http://wso2.org/claims/nickname</ClaimUri>
          <claimId>0</claimId>
        </LocalClaim>
        <RemoteClaim>
          <ClaimUri>http://wso2.org/claims/nickname</ClaimUri>
          <claimId>0</claimId>
        </RemoteClaim>
        <RequestClaim>true</RequestClaim>
        <MandatoryClaim>false</MandatoryClaim>
      </ClaimMapping>
      <ClaimMapping>
        <LocalClaim>
          <ClaimUri>http://wso2.org/claims/identity/emailVerified</ClaimUri>
          <claimId>0</claimId>
        </LocalClaim>
        <RemoteClaim>
          <ClaimUri>http://wso2.org/claims/identity/emailVerified</ClaimUri>
          <claimId>0</claimId>
        </RemoteClaim>
        <RequestClaim>true</RequestClaim>
        <MandatoryClaim>false</MandatoryClaim>
      </ClaimMapping>
    </ClaimMappings>
    <AlwaysSendMappedLocalSubjectId>false</AlwaysSendMappedLocalSubjectId>
    <SPClaimDialects>
      <SPClaimDialect>http://wso2.org/oidc/claim</SPClaimDialect>
    </SPClaimDialects>
  </ClaimConfig>
  <PermissionAndRoleConfig>
    <Permissions/>
    <RoleMappings/>
    <IdpRoles/>
  </PermissionAndRoleConfig>
  <IsSaaSApp>false</IsSaaSApp>
</ServiceProvider>
```

Notice : It's needed to change Mattermost Gitlab configuration URL from /ouath/ to /oauth2/ for Wso2is.

Thank you

Regards

Comment: Do you see any errors in Mattermost logs?

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Mattermost log are not quiet helpful. There is only one message : "runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference". According mattermost FAQ it's a read/creation database issue : https://docs.mattermost.com/install/troubleshooting.html#panic-runtime-error-invalid-memory-address-or-nil-pointer-dereference. This issue is consistent with the Claim configuration issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was unable to solve this issue with wso2is. Indeed, it does appear wso2is doesn't send claims with the token.
Moreover, Git token structure uses an integer as ID, not a string. So, is not possible to use the default user GUID generated be almost all IAM.

To answer my need, I found another solution: KeyCloak.
KeyCloak works fine and it allow to define claims by code, so it's possible to auto-generate the integer ID needed for Mattermost.

Regards,